# How to change last segment of url with php preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have urls like this:

```
/img/products/loop/blabla/81.jpg
/img/products/loop/blabla/asasd/811234.jpg
/img/productsasdasd.jpg
```

I want to replace this url's like this:

```
/img/products/loop/blabla/null.jpg
/img/products/loop/blabla/asasd/null.jpg
/img/null.jpg
```

How to done this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $string="/img/products/loop/blabla/81.jpg";
   echo preg_replace("/[A-Za-z0-9]+[.]/","null.",$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it although you may also want to look at [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
<?php

$urls = array(
  '/img/products/loop/blabla/81.jpg',
  '/img/products/loop/blabla/asasd/811234.jpg',
  '/img/productsasdasd.jpg'
);

foreach ($urls as $url) {
  var_dump(preg_replace('#/\w+(\.\w+)$#', '/null$1', $url));
}
```